# Replace String from DataFrame "\N"

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe, pyspark

Here is Sample DataFrame :

```
    resultId,raceId,driverId,fastestLapTime  
      1,      18,      1,        01:27.5  
      2,      18,      2,        01:27.7  
      3,      18,      3,          \N  
      4,      18,      4,        01:28.9  
      5,      18,      5,          \N  
      6,      18,      6,          \N
```

I want to replace \N with some random value suppose -100 ,

```
result_df.withColumn('fastestLapTime',regexp_replace('fastestLapTime','\N','-100')).show(1)
```

I am getting following error

```
(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: malformed \N character escape
```

Answer (score -2):

That is happening because the `"\N"` is interpreted in python as an unicode character. You should use `"\\N"` instead.

Moreover, I would recomend you to use the `loc` function of pandas:

```
result_df.loc[result_df['fastestLapTime']=='\\N','fastestLapTime'] = -100
```

Hope this helps you.